# When i try to assembleRelease got an error?

Tags: react-native

> Task :app:mergeReleaseResources FAILED
> w: Detected multiple Kotlin daemon sessions at build\kotlin\sessions

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileRunnable
> Android resource compilation failed
> ERROR:C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Vendor\android\app\build\generated\res\react\release\drawable-mdpi\assets_platform.png: AAPT: error: file failed to compile.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)
- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

Execution optimizations have been disabled for 1 invalid unit(s) of work during this build to ensure correctness.
Please consult deprecation warnings for more details.

I try to bulid apk with localhost to check my application